# Drupal 7. Почему нельзя залогиниться с технического домена и восстановить пароль?

Tags: drupal, password-hash

Добрый день. Есть сайт на Drupal 7, vinokuram.ru. Для удобства работы с ним я скопировал его в другую папку на том же хостинге, создал копию базы, папка на хостинге именуется testvinokuram.ru. Отдельного доменного имени заводить не стал на него, обращение к нему из браузера получается по тестовому домену testvinokuram.ru.показать.сайт.

Проблема в том, что при обращении к копии сайта по тестовому домену - невозможно залогиниться в админку, сразу говорит "логин или пароль неверны". Ссылки на восстановление пароля присылает в виде:
http://testvinokuram.ru/user/reset/1/1471151912/g5a3pbM-1vY5IjxxODyL9491d8lCl16h<бла-бла-бла>

Т.е. как видим, имя сайта при восстановлении пароля на почту приходит вовсе не то, через которое доступен тестовый сайт в браузере. Естественно, такая ссылка не срабатывает - а при попытке дописать в эту ссылку ".показать.сайт" ссылка становится нерабочей.

Смена $base_url в settings.php делает недоступными все картинки и съезжает вёрстка. Куда копать, чтобы я мог попасть в админку тестового сайта?

PS. Заранее признателен.

Answer (score 1):

Если свести вашу задачу к "перенести друпал на другой домен" (а задача "сделать копию друпала на другом домене" практически не отличается от этой), то делается всё элементарно: переносите файлы, копируете базу данных, чистите кэш друпала. И всё заработает.

Почему не работает у вас. Многие хостеры предлагают быстрый способ создания сайта -- завели ещё одну папку, залили файлы -- и сайт видится по какому-нибудь техническому адресу типа [http://имяпапки.доменпровайдера.ру](http://%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8.%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0.%D1%80%D1%83)
Но что-то вы сделали неправильно и разбираться нужно именно в этом - вам копать нужно именно на стороне провайдера услуг: как конкретно он это делает и что химичит. Подробнее смотрите сами, ру-со -- это не бесплатный фриланс и вашу работу за вас никто не сделает.

Вообще, стремление отойти от правки кода на продакшн сайте -- похвально. Вы решили собрать окружение разработчика прямо у хостера,  на том же сервере -- это не очень хорошо. Подымите окружение у себя на рабочем компьютере и используйте два окружения: development и production. То, что вы делаете у хостера можно считать скорее ближе к staging. Это модель (dev -> stage -> prod) ближе к идеалу, но и накладные расходы выше.

Comment: На локалхосте этот сколько ни пытался Друпал запускать на разных Апачах (как просто Apache под Windows, так и XAMPP) - страшные тормоза. Нетбук Lenovo S10-3. Интересно, что Wordpress-сайты на локалке летают.

Comment: @NDanilov2015 Притча говорит, что "искать надо там, где потерял, а не там где светлее". Правильнее разобраться с проблемой, почему локально друпал тормозит (у других же не тормозит), а не создавать себе новые проблемы, идя по неверной дорожке.

Comment: Я грешил на слабенький ноут, хотя загрузка CPU Апачем при этом не очень велика. Ладно, попробую разобраться что не так в localhost